# How to render user profile (actual image) instead of filename in a Django form which basically update user-account

Tags: python, html, django

I am following a Django course on youtube, and I need a small change in my Django form.

The form looks like:

[image]

Rendering the form fields in 'edit-user.html' template:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-input">
        <label for="id_{{field.label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
        {{field}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div id="lrf-options">
        <div id="lrf-btn">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**What I am actually asking:
So in Avatar Currently: 1044-3840x2160.jpg, I want actual image to display here instead of <filename>.**

I think maybe I need to change my forms.py to generate <img> tag instead if <a> tag but I don't know how to do this.

models.py

```
class UserModel(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 90)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
    about = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="avatar.svg")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

and forms.py is:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ['avatar', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'about']
```

and in views.py the update function is:

```
def editUserProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    form = UserForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('chat:userProfileView', uname = user.username)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'chat/edit-user.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `request.user.avatar.url` instead of currently url.Hide input and use jquery to give a click to input:

```
<div class="form-input">
    <label for="id_Avatar">Avatar</label>
    Currently:
    <img id="current-avatar" src="{{request.user.avatar.url}}"/>
    <br>
    <a id="change-avatar">Change</a>
    <input id="avatar-input" style="display:none;" type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" id="id_avatar">
</div>


<script>
$("#change-avatar").click(function(){
   $("#avatar-input").click();
});
</script>
```

If you don't have jQuery add this to your main HTML:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Assalamualaykum. This html I got from the for loop above, I pasted it by inspection the page on browser, I don't have this code in my app, it get generated by for loop. This for loop is in 'edit-user.html' template. I am passing a form in editUserProfile() function in views.py and then rendering that form in 'edit-user.html' template using for loop. Sorry for confusing. First time posting a question.

Comment: Alaykumassalam. I see. If you can share your Github repository I can send you a pull request. At least I will see the 'edit-user.html' profile so can help you.

Comment: [Github repository](https://github.com/Rafay106/Django/tree/master/DjangoChatApp)

Comment: @Rafay106 Please check my pull request on GitHub

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, now I understand what you were saying.

Comment: You are welcome. That was nice to help.